# Syntax error when trying to insert data into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i was trying to use a button that insert all data from textbox into database but get error when i click the button. here's the code:

```
protected void orderBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ChocolateDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("Insert into Order(Cardholder, CardNumber, CardExpireDate, CardCVV, Address, PayAmount) values (@Cardholder, @CardNumber, @CardExpireDate, @CardCVV, @Address, @PayAmount)", con2);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cardholder", cName.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardNumber", cNo.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardExpireDate", cExpire.SelectedDate);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardCVV", cCCV.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", cAddr.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayAmount", totalTB.Text);

    con2.Open();
    insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con2.Close();
}
```

i already checked the table and the column name, they are all correct.

Comment: is shows the error `incorrect syntax near the keyword Order`.

Comment: Is it maybe complaining cause Order is a [reserved SQL keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @hanlet well u are correct! order is a command word in sql after i change my table name it all work correctly!

Answer (score 3):

Since Order is a keyword, you need to wrap the table name with brackets:

```
SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("Insert into [Order](Cardholder, CardNumber, CardExpireDate, CardCVV, Address, PayAmount) values (@Cardholder, @CardNumber, @CardExpireDate, @CardCVV, @Address, @PayAmount)", con2);
```

The reason you can use brackets is because Microsoft SQL Server does not recognize variable names that are delimited.

My preference is not to use keywords as names for tables and columns. But this is not a rule, it is a convention. Using keywords as names can make confusion but in other hand it can make the code clearer to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Order] Instead of  Order because Order is Delimiter For Example 
We Use order keyword when we use Order by clause so when we write it as our object name we have to put it as [Order] otherwise it will treated as keyword

```
Insert into [Order] (Cardholder, CardNumber, CardExpireDate, CardCVV, Address, PayAmount) values (@Cardholder, @CardNumber, @CardExpireDate, @CardCVV, @Address, @PayAmount
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the order of insert operation you are performing is wrong it should be something like this :

```
 SqliteCommand _mysqlcmd ;
 connectDataBase();//myCon2.open here as it depends how you are connecting
_mysqlcmd = con2.CreateCommand();
_mysqlcmd.CommandText = "Insert query.....";
_mysqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("","");//same for all Insertion
_mysqlcmd.ExecuteQuery();
```

Check it with this code may it help you somewhat ...!!!